# Visual Studio 2010 : fatal error C1189: #error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc

Error : 1   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h 24

Possible solutions / workarounds :

1. C/C++ | Advanced | Show Includes : not working
2. MFC is required, set the following values ( Debug/Win32 ):

Configuration Properties > General :

Use of MFC : Use MFC in a Shared DLL
Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation :

Runtime Library : /MDd : Not Working

3. USE of MFC' is in 'Use MFC in a Shared DLL' setting : Not working

Kindly request to provide suggestion / solution for the mentioned issue.

Many thanks !!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question already contains the answer. The OP is not going to understand the answer, if we copy-paste it for them.

Comment: Yes I know,but already I have mentioned the possible workaround / solutions are not working in my case

Comment: *"Does not work"* is not an error description.

Comment: Error description is already given, request you to cross check the question posted

Comment: You did not list why the suggested workarounds do not work. I am talking about:  ***Runtime Library : /MDd : Not Working*** ...How is it not working? Compiler errors? Linker Errors? What errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have access right now to VS but, for what I do remind:
1- you need a non express version for MFC, which i suppose you have (?)
2- If you set `Use MFC in static library` THEN you should activate the `multithreading (/Mt)` or the debug version `(/Mtd)`
3- If you set `Use MFC as shared library` THEN you should activate the `Multi-threaded DLL (/Md)` ou the debug version `(/Mdd)`

When they are not put accordingly you have those kind of fatal error.